# Uploading excel sheet and mapping it to different model classes

Tags: c#, excel, models, mapper

I am working with uploading of excel files. I converted it to `datatable` as follows.

```
public static DataTable ConvertExcelFileToDataTable(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    // ExcelDataReader works with the binary Excel file, so it needs a FileStream
    // to get started. This is how we avoid dependencies on ACE or Interop:
    Stream stream = upload.InputStream;
    IExcelDataReader reader = null;
    if (upload.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
    {
        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
    }
    else if (upload.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
    {
        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
    }
    reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
    DataTable dtProductCatalog = reader.AsDataSet().Tables[0];
    reader.Close();

    return dtProductCatalog;
}
```

Now i want to create a *mapper type thing* that will contain that which `datatable column` will convert to which model. And then convert the `datatable` into respective list of models. I am not sure how to start with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a model factory which will be responsible for returning you your desired model. You can then add each model to a list.

In the below example, we have a `BaseModel` class which holds properties common to all models if needed. But has an overrideable populate method. Then create the sub classes which inherit your base model for each model type you have. Below i've just done `Model1`.

```
public class BaseModel
{
    //Common Properties here.
    public virtual void PopulateData(DataTable data)
    {
        //Override
    }
}

public class Model1 : BaseModel
{
    //Model 1 Properties here.
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override void PopulateData(DataTable data)
    {
       //Set all model values here from datatable.      
    }
}



public class ModelFactory
{
    private BaseModel _model;

    public BaseModel ReturnModelByName(string modelName, DataTable dtProductCatalog)
    {
        switch (modelName)
       {
            case "Model1":
                _model = new Model1();
                _model.PopulateData(dtProductCatalog);
                break;

            case "Model2": //etc....
                break;
        }      
        return _model;
    }
}
```

Then use the `ModelFactory` class to return you a populated instance of the model you want based upon the model name.

You can call the factory for each model.

```
var modelFactory = new ModelFactory();
var modelList = new List<BaseModel>();
var myModel = modelFactory.ReturnModelForColumn("Model1", dtProductCatalog);

modelList.Add(myModel);
```

Hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: How can we keep like 3 columns in one model, 4 in others using this approach?

Comment: I've changed the design to what you need. The model is now "Model1".  The factory now takes the model name you want to populate.  Each model will have it's own overrideable populate method which takes the data table so you can take any column value to populate the fields as required.

Comment: Great and is there any way of mapping between excel columns to list of different models direct without datatable step

Comment: Well you could pass the Excel document into the factory and pass as the parameter for the populate method. You can then manipulate the excel object as you wish.